# with openlayers 4, how to fit a wfs request to the current view and limit it to a minimum zoom level and above

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm viewing parcels with openlayers 4 and I don't know how to fit a wfs request to the current view and limit it to a minimum zoom level and above (because of the 1000 limit). currently the result only returns the first 1000 parcels that have nothing to do with the displayed map view.
This request is

```
     var parcellaireSource =  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'https://wxs.ign.fr/api key/geoportail/wfs?request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BDPARCELLAIRE-VECTEUR_WLD_BDD_WGS84G:parcelle&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:2154&' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:2154';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
        });
     var parcellairewfs =  new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: parcellaireSource
      });
```

Comment: I've got my own answerthere
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642651/openlayers-strategy-ol-loadingstrategy-bbox-doesnt-work-with-wfs-features/47650340#47650340

Comment: fyi, you can close or answer yourself so that the question wont showup as "unresolved" anymore in people's stream

Comment: I don't know how to close this question

Comment: I've got my own answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642651/openlayers-strategy-ol-loadingstrategy-bbox-doesnt-work-with-wfs-features/47650340#47650340

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openlayers strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox does'nt work with wfs features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642651/openlayers-strategy-ol-loadingstrategy-bbox-doesnt-work-with-wfs-features)

Comment: hello and thanks for your reply
As I sad I found a solution
the "strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox," works fine with wfs and return extent and resolution.
see my solution there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642651/openlayers-strategy-ol-loadingstrategy-bbox-doesnt-work-with-wfs-features/47650340#47650340