# openlayers strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox does'nt work with wfs features

Tags: openlayers

I tried to visualize parcels in wfs with openlayers 4 (max 1000) with this code.
But the extent does not change at each movement or zoom of the view map, or the new features do not load in the layer?

```
 var parcellaireSource =  new ol.source.Vector({ 
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function (extent) {
      return  'https://wxs.ign.fr/api key/geoportail/wfs?request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BDPARCELLAIRE-VECTEUR_WLD_BDD_WGS84G:parcelle&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:2154&bbox='+ extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';

          },

    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });
     var parcellairewfs =  new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: parcellaireSource
  });
     map.addLayer(parcellairewfs);
```

Comment: It works know when I ad
function onMoveEnd(evt) {
        parcellaireSource.clear()

        console.log(view.getResolution());
        console.log(parcellaireSource);
      }
       map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
But, because of the number of features limit, I want to load them only on a certain zoom level. Do you see how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

It works know when I add

```
function onMoveEnd(evt) { parcellaireSource.clear() } map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
```

But, because of the number of features limit, I want to load them only on a certain zoom level. Do you see how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's done with

```
  url: function (extent,resolution) {if (resolution<1) {return ....
```

in the vectorsource calculation and adding resolution parameter to the function